# How to deploy Jhipster stack to AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster

I built my monolith application using Jhipster stack with React front-end. I can run my application normally. I want to deploy my app to AWS.

I followed [the guide](https://www.jhipster.tech/aws/) then run `jhipster aws`. Everything is fine. Here is the log:

```
PS E:\source\vpark> jhipster aws
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! No custom sharedOptions found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-react-antd at C:/Users/dungreact/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster-react-antd
INFO! No custom commands found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-react-antd at C:/Users/dungreact/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster-react-antd
? Application name: vpark
? Environment name: vpark-env
? Name of S3 bucket: vpark-s3
? Database name: vpark
? Database username: root
? Database password: [hidden]
? On which EC2 instance type do you want to deploy? t2.small
? On which RDS instance class do you want to deploy? db.t2.micro
? On which region do you want to deploy? us-west-1
Building application
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :bootBuildInfo
> Task :nodeSetup UP-TO-DATE
> Task :npmSetup UP-TO-DATE

> Task :npm_install

up to date, audited 1677 packages in 24s

165 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

> Task :webapp

> vpark@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webapp:prod
> npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:prod


> vpark@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT clean-www
> rimraf build/resources/main/static/app/{src,build/}


> vpark@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webapp:build:prod
> npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress=profile


> vpark@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack
> node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--progress=profile"

assets by status 576 KiB [cached] 5 assets
assets by status 5.06 MiB [compared for emit]
  assets by path content/ 1.24 MiB
    assets by status 1.08 MiB [big] 2 assets
  assets by path swagger-ui/ 3.77 MiB 14 assets
  assets by status 5.4 KiB [emitted]
    asset service-worker.js 3.61 KiB [emitted] [compared for emit] [minimized]
    asset index.html 1.79 KiB [emitted] [compared for emit]
  assets by path ./i18n/*.json 24.1 KiB
    asset ./i18n/vi.json 12.9 KiB [compared for emit]
    asset ./i18n/en.json 11.2 KiB [compared for emit]
  4 assets
assets by path app/*.js 1.63 MiB
  asset app/vendors.f5ebb1aa658a977e2d40.bundle.js 1.51 MiB [emitted] [immutable] [minimized] [big] (name: vendors) (id hint: commons) 1 related asset
  asset app/main.e88c24c5e7a0c24765e4.bundle.js 120 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [minimized] (name: main)
Entrypoint main [big] 2.15 MiB = app/vendors.f5ebb1aa658a977e2d40.bundle.js 1.51 MiB content/main.237501a1e51be6d9143b.css 533 KiB app/main.e88c24c5e7a0c24765e4.bundle.js 120 KiB
cached modules 5.87 MiB (javascript) 551 KiB (css/mini-extract) [cached] 1510 modules
runtime modules 11 KiB 15 modules
orphan modules 37.5 KiB [orphan] 1 module
javascript modules 120 KiB
  ./src/main/webapp/app/shared/reducers/locale.ts 1.21 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/rc-field-form/es/index.js + 14 modules 114 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/react-jhipster/lib/src/util/log-util.js 1.93 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js 2.57 KiB [built] [code generated]

LOG from GenerateSW
<i> The service worker at service-worker.js will precache
<i>         32 URLs, totaling 3.62 MB.

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  content/images/logo.png (318 KiB)
  content/images/map.png (788 KiB)
  swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js (1.13 MiB)
  swagger-ui/swagger-ui-es-bundle-core.js (518 KiB)
  swagger-ui/swagger-ui-es-bundle.js (1.13 MiB)
  swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js (343 KiB)
  swagger-ui/swagger-ui.js (518 KiB)
  content/main.237501a1e51be6d9143b.css (533 KiB)
  app/vendors.f5ebb1aa658a977e2d40.bundle.js (1.51 MiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (2.15 MiB)
      app/vendors.f5ebb1aa658a977e2d40.bundle.js
      content/main.237501a1e51be6d9143b.css
      app/main.e88c24c5e7a0c24765e4.bundle.js


webpack 5.51.1 compiled with 2 warnings in 23251 ms

> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateGitProperties
> Task :classes
> Task :bootWar

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 15s
9 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 4 up-to-date

Create S3 bucket
Bucket vpark-s-3 created successfully

Upload WAR to S3
War uploaded successful

Create database
Database created successfully

Waiting for database (This may take several minutes)
Database available at jdbc:mysql://vpark.culndou2fn7b.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/vpark

Verifying ElasticBeanstalk Roles

Create/Update application
Environment vpark-env created successfully
    force .yo-rc.json

No change to package.json was detected. No package manager install will be executed.
Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
Sponsored with ❤️  by @oktadev.
```

Then I open Elastic Beanstalk console. Enviroment is `green` but Platform (Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux) is Deprecated.

I tried to open the application address `http://xxx.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/` and it just show HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.63
```

I don't know where is wrong. I can't find other tutorial about this

Answer (score 1):

I had many issues with running JHipster on AWS as well, I don't think that it's being updated and maintained.

At first, try creating and deploying it manually on AWS, that will give you more flexibility to do the things the way you need it and more information to be able to debug. In the end, JHipster will be a Spring Boot application, and any Spring Boot AWS deployment tutorial should work.